# Syntax error, unexpected non-printable character with the hex value '0xa0'

Tags: verilog, spi

i see this error when compile slave module,how to fix it?

** Error: (vlog-13067) C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/Spi/spi_slave.v(2.0): Syntax error, unexpected non-printable character with the hex value '0xa0'.

here is my code:
Visit https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2rVJBk_oSMJbGVNTnp0NnVoNlE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some funny character in your code. That's what the error message is telling you. Replace it with a space and the error message goes away.

I got an error message for column 2 of line 14 in your code here - https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4s_P. I replaced it with a space and the error disappeared. You will see that there are many more errors where you need to do the same thing.